# how to conditionally replace values in columns with value of specific column in the same line by Unix and awk commands

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I want to conditionally replace values in columns with value of specific column in the same line in one file, by Unix and awk commands.

For example, I have myfile.txt (3 lines, 5 columns, tab-delimited):

```
1 A . C .
2 C T . T
3 T C C .
```

There are "." in columns 3 to 5. I want to replace those "." in columns 3 - 5 with the value in column 2 on the same line.

Could you please show me any directions on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do what you're asking for:

```
% awk 'BEGIN {
     IFS = OFS = "\t"
  }
  {
     for (column = 3; column <= NF; ++column) {
        if ($column == ".") {
            $column = $2
        }
     }    
     print 
  }         
' test.tsv
1       A       A       C       A
2       C       T       C       T
3       T       C       C       T
```

You've asked a few questions (and accepted no answers!) on awk now. May 
I humbly suggest [a tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)?

Comment: Thanks, Johnsyweb and glenn jackman. I learned much from your script and comment.

Comment: you should set OFS to tab otherwise the delimitor will be inconsistent in the result records.

Comment: Thanks @glenn jackman, @jlliagre: I've updated my script to provide more clarity and consistency.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{FS="\t"; for(i=3;i<=5;i++) if($i==".") $i=$2; print}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Very attractive awk script. I have learned much from you. Thanks Jlliagre.